# How to use VPN and native IP at the same time?

Tags: vpn

I have two PCs: One in NJ one in FL. I want to keep them synced for backup purposes. For the past 2 years I have been using Teamviewer where I create a VPN and then use a sync program to sync the two PCs. The key point is I can initiate the VPN on PC2 from PC1. I can turn the VPN on and off on both PCs from PC1.

Now, however, Teamviewer is saying I'm a commercial user (I'm not) and will not run, so I'm looking for an alternative.

I settled on RemotePC for remote control access, and am looking how to set up a VPN. I did a remote connection to pc2 and tried running a VPN (Surfshark) on PC2. As soon as the VPN started I could no longer control the PC via RemotePC as it disconnected.

I need to access PC2 after the VPN starts so I can see the VPN IP address and use it to identify PC2 to the sync program. Not sure how to get this done. After vpn started on PC2 I had to remotely power cycle PC2 — thank goodness for internet accessible plugs! — to be able to access it again.

I hope what I'm trying to do is clear.

What's frustrating is that I've been syncing PC1 and PC2 for 2 years now using the TeamViewer VPN, it worked great. All I need now is an alternative.

---

I am trying out SurfShark as the VPN.  If I can get both pc's on the same subnet I would then use Syncovery to do the synchronization. I'm not locked into any VPN so if you know of one that would better address this problem please let me know.

I don't intend that the VPN handle only the sync traffic, rather, once both pc's are on the same subnet one of the benefits is that identifying/accessing each pc to syncovery then becomes simple. Again, my problem seems to be that once the VPN kicks in on the remote pc, I loose the remote control connection. It appears (based on what I saw) that the TeamViewer VPN connection created a subnet that didn't take over all connections. It just sat there until you specifically accessed the remote pc via its vpn ip address.

Comment: Surely you know the VPN IP because you configured it?  What systems are you using?  Make sure you provide full information for us to answer the correction correctly.  How are you keeping them synced?  There are solutions that allow that without requiring a VPN.

Comment: You want the VPN to only handle the sync traffic. That's a VPN config question and depends on the product you are using.

Comment: Keep in mind that SE sites are not forums but Q/A sites. // SurfShark is not the kind of VPN you’re looking for. It’s not for linking remote PCs in a shared network.

Comment: OpenVPN sounds like it would be a better fit of a VPN for you, and if you want to remotely control the server from one PC, it would be best to install OpenVPN on the router at the remote location.  If you don't have a router whose OEM firmware comes with OpenVPN, I would recommend flashing the opensource firmware [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) onto your router.  You can look up if your router is supported [here](https://openwrt.org/toh/start) and if it's not, an affordable router that fully supports OpenWrt out of the box would be any Linksys WRT AC/ACS/ACM router (1200AC, 1900ACS, 3200ACM).